# Shows all the product of a List

Tags: android, listview, view

I'm trying to display all the products in an activity in a list of my db. I used NewView and BindView. Rather than show me all the elements (barcode, format, title, price), I see only the last, price. any solution is appreciated! :)  Here is the part of the code:

```
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + PRODUCT_TABLE, null);

        setListAdapter(new CursorAdapter(this, cursor, true) {

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){

            TextView textView = new TextView(ProdottiSelectionActivity.this);
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("barcode")));
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("format")));
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("price")));
            return textView;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){

            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("barcode")));
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("format")));
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("price")));

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use textView.append() instead of setText

Comment: in which format u want to display? if you want space then append one space in between

Comment: I think this is better .. but it's better one under the other

Comment: sorry I misspelled...i need to view the elements one under the other..:)